# Back to Questions when clicking physical back key (mobile app)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, android-app

I'm not sure if there's a better place to ask this, but;

When viewing a question on the mobile Stack Overflow app, clicking the physical back key returns you to the tags menu. Should this not take you back to the list of questions instead filtered by your already chosen tag? I.e;

**Current App Flow**

1. load app
2. Choose tags view
3. Filter by tag (e.g., JavaScript) to show questions
4. View question
5. Press physical back key - returns you to step 2

Should step 5 not return you back to step 3? The only way to do so is to click the back arrow in the top left corner.

Not sure if it matters, but this is on Android. (Don't have an iOS device to see if the functionality is the same.)

Thoughts?

Comment: Ooo, I did not know that pressing back twice (counter intuitive) takes me back to where I want to go. However, that question is a year old and the issue (if it is even technically an issue) is still present.

Comment: there is no one working on the apps anymore so it’ll probably still be an issue in another year...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is [standard Android design](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal#up-vs-back). The (physical) back button takes you back to the previous page (like a browser would do); the one in the top left corner is the 'up' button and it takes you one level up.

> The Up button appears in the app bar and is used to navigate within an app based on the hierarchical relationships between screens.
>
> The Back button appears in the system navigation bar and is used to navigate, in reverse chronological order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between screens, rather than the app's hierarchy.

iOS devices don't have a physical back button; the back button in the top left corner acts in the same way as the physical back button on Android.

Comment: Wouldn't the questions view be the previous page rather than tags? I'd expect the current way if questions were displayed as a modal, but it is displayed as a page?

Comment: So from your edits, it seems as if the Android app has been built to mimic the iOS style of navigation. The physical button on Android feels as though it takes me back two screens (from question -> questions list -> to tags). It might be my misunderstanding of app flow, but it's frustrating to press back from a question (as feels natural) and end up having to reselect the tag to view more questions...

Comment: The back button on iOS takes you back to the question list not the tag page

Comment: Wait, I've misunderstood the question and will delete this.